# No view found for Id (for fragment)

Tags: android, fragment

What I am trying is ,Calling a fragment from one of my activity but it throws the following error .I know I am not the first to ask this ,I have tried all the solution which related to my question but nothing is solved my issue.

Error :

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08005f (com.aviz.www.reminder:id/mAddAlarm) for fragment AlarmCreater{88da1f5 #0 id=0x7f08005f AlarmCreater}
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2415)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2194)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2148)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2049)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:718)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
```

Comment: You should  provide container id inside `replace` . `R.id.mAddAlarm` is not the container .

Comment: is the linearlayout the root layout?

Comment: @D.'s yes ,fragment and activity both are having the Linearlayout as parent layout

Comment: do you have a view pager?in your main activity

Comment: @D.'s no I don't have

Answer (score 1):

**mAddIcon** is the ID of layout on which you will be adding that fragment, So that ID should be in layout from which Activity/Fragment you want to add `AlarmCreater`.

In shorts **mAddIcon** should be on your `AlarmActivity` layout (`R.layout.activity_alarm`), You can take it as `FrameLayout`/`RelativeLayout`/`LinearLayout`.

`fragment_alarm_creater.xml` is your fragment's layout (view). So mAddIcon is not getting find by Activity.

You can put same linearLayout in your `R.layout.activity_alarm` layout.

Ex. Use this xml in `R.layout.activity_alarm`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mDeleteIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_sweep_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:text="Alarm"
        android:textColor="@color/tab_background"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mAddIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/mRecyclerView_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/mAddAlarm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so what should I given in the place of "R.id.________"

Comment: put that R.layout.activity_alarm  layout in question, i will share you example

Comment: posted all my codes here,Please guide me to fix that issue

Comment: use my posted xml

Comment: please see my updated "activity_alarm.xml" file 
and How can I keep two Id's in the same naming in a same xml file